# Is_file возвращает true на директорию

Tags: php

Есть директория с поддиректориями, которые необходимо перебрать и выполнить для них определенные действия:

```
  while($dir = readdir($heandler)){ // где $heandler - родительская директория
    if(!is_file($dir)){
      // какие-то действия
    }
  }
```

Так вот: для одной из папок `is_file` упорно возвращает `true`. Я даже не знаю, как диагностировать проблему. Смотрел вывод `ls -la` - для всех директорий одинаковый вывод, так что думаю проблема не в ОС. `clearstatcache` не помогает, а вот переименование директории решает проблему, да только мне такой вариант не подходит (папка - модуль yii, слишком много путей придется поменять).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is_file должен получать корректный путь от базового скрипта. А readdir возвращает просто имя. И если допустить ситуацию вида (структура каталогов и файлов, + поставлен напротив каталогов)

```
 script.php 
 test
+dir 
   foo
   bar
  +test
     foo1
     bar1
```

В таком случае каталог test может быть "файлом". и переименования действительно поможет. Пример кода посмотрите [здесь](http://forum.php.su/topic.php?forum=75&topic=2479).